# How do I convert user input into a list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm wondering how to take user input and make a list of every character in it.

```
magicInput = input('Type here: ')
```

And say you entered "python rocks"
I want a to make it a list something like this

```
magicList = [p,y,t,h,o,n, ,r,o,c,k,s]
```

But if I do this:

```
magicInput = input('Type here: ')
magicList = [magicInput]
```

The magicList is just

```
['python rocks']
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the built-in `list()` function:

```
magicInput = input('Type here: ')
magicList = list(magicInput)
print(magicList)
```

**Output**

```
['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', ' ', 'r', 'o', 'c', 'k', 's']
```

Answer (score 3):

It may not be necessary to do any conversion, because the string supports many list operations. For instance:

```
print(magicInput[1])
print(magicInput[2:4])
```

Output:

```
y
th
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way would be to traverse the input and construct a list taking each letter

```
magicInput = input('Type here: ')
list_magicInput = []
for letter in magicInput:
    list_magicInput.append(letter)
```

Comment: Not quite the *most* basic.  See gtlambart's answer.

Comment: @zondo, simple way I guess.

Comment: *That* I'll agree with.

Comment: @zondo, not very well versed with python. :)

Answer (score 1):

or you can simply do

```
x=list(input('Thats the input: ')
```

and it converts the thing you typed it as a list

Answer (score -1):

```
a=list(input()).
```

It converts the input into a list just like when we want to convert the input into an integer.

```
a=(int(input())) #typecasts input to int
```

Answer (score -1):

using list comprehension,

```
magicInput = [_ for _ in input("Enter String:")]

print('magicList = [{}]'.format(', '.join(magicInput)))
```

produces

```
Enter String:python rocks
magicList = [p, y, t, h, o, n,  , r, o, c, k, s]
```

You can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to concatenate strings with a specified separator.
Furthermore, in your case, [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) may also help.
However the apostrophes will not interfere with anything you do with the list. The apostrophes show that the elements are strings.

Method 2:

```
magicInput = ','.join(input('Enter String: '))
print(f'\nmagicList: [{magicInput}]')
```

Edit 1:

```
user_input = input("Enter String:")
magic_list = list(user_input)

print(f'magic_list = {magic_list}')
```

This code captures the user input as a string and then converts it into a list of characters using list().